# Удаление файла через 10 секунд после создания

Tags: php

Как удалить файл через 10 секунд, после его создания?
Пытался реализовать через: `sleep(10);`. Но задерживается выполнение и создания, и удаления.

Comment: смысл то сего действа каков?

Comment: @teran, да, Вы правы. Это глупое действие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После создания файла скрипт будет ждать (спать) 10 секунд, после чего файл будет удален.

```
$pathFile = 'test.txt';
file_put_contents($pathFile, 'content to file');
sleep(10);
unlink($pathFile);
```

Имеет значение порядок выполнения операторов: сначала создается файл, а только после этого запускается sleep() и процесс удаления.